# NSXMLDocument - Modifying nodes / attributes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsxmldocument

Is there a simple way to update nodes in an NSXMLDocument? I come from a c# background and you can do a simple `XmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("XPATH")` to select a node and `XmlNode.InnerText = "abc"` to set the value of the node.

I can't seem to find any methods that let me do this in the Apple [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation?

Thanks, 
Teja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSXMLDocument` is a subclass of [`NSXMLNode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSXMLNode) which has a method [`nodesForXPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLNode_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002408-BCIDHHDB) which will, it seems, give you an array containing the nodes you're after. Something along these lines:

```
NSError err;
NSArray * nodes = [myXMLDoc nodesForXPath:theXPath error:&err];
if( !nodes ){ 
    // handle error
}
[[nodes objectAtIndex:0] setStringValue:@"abc"];
```

There may be another method than `setStringValue:` that you want to call on the resulting node, perhaps.

<sub>(If the thing with the `NSError` made you say "WTF?", give the [Error Handling Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/CreateCustomizeNSError/CreateCustomizeNSError.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH204-BAJIIGCC) a quick glance.)</sub>